# What's the best practice for patching a full data column?

Tags: bokeh

I have a large data source with many columns and want to replace the data of a single column completele. Let's call the column `temperature`. I want to use `source.patch(..)` to avoid re-sending the remaining data columns that haven't changed. Currently I am using:

```py
new_temperatures = [1,2,3]
patches = {'temperature': list(enumerate(new_temperatures))}
source.patch(patches)
```

Is this the recommended approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bokeh is [very observant](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/7a4e3efb02780249820f10cb6b9f40d4597a556a/bokeh/core/property/wrappers.py#L357-L395). You can update the one column you want directly, and Bokeh will only send that column:

```
source.data['temperature'] = new_temps
```

You just have to be careful, when updating like that, that `new_temps` is the same length as the existing other columns.

Comment: so I could even use `source.data.update({'temperature': [1,2,3]})`?

Comment: Yes, in fact that is what Bokeh does internally.